# CSS Absolute Position Not Positioning a Button

Tags: html, css, absolute

Good morning!

I have a background image that I am trying to place some text and some buttons. I can place the text (only using padding it seems) but cannot get my button to place correctly. I've tried dozens of different workarounds but can't get anything to work. Any help is much appreciated!

The page: http://tradecaptain.com/nlp
My css/html. Its not pretty. I'm just learning. The broken css id is .video at the end of the code.

```
<style type="text/css">
.outer {
position: relative;
background: url(/images/LandingPageTopBlend.png);
width: 960px;
height: 300px;
}
.Line1 {
line-height: 10px;
padding-top: 50px;
text-align: center;
font-size:26px;
font-family:Verdana;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
}
.Line2 {
text-align: right;
padding-right: 45px;
padding-top: 15px;
font-size:10px;
font-family:Verdana;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
}
.Line3 {
line-height: 10px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 45px;
padding-top: 30px;
font-size:26px;
font-family:Verdana;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
}
.video {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 260px;
left: 100px;
}   </style>
<div class="outer">
<div class="Line1"><h1>The Simple Way to Trading Profit</h1></div>
<div class="Line2"><h1>trading forex stocks commodities futures</h1></div>
<div class="Line3"><h1>The TradeMap. Trade like a pro.</h1></div>
<div id="video">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DYkSNur2Rc" rel="lightvideo"><img alt="How to Trade Video" src="/images/WatchVideo.png" style="width: 136px; height: 34px;" /></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.video` is a class, an ID would be `#video`, it's just a typo.

Comment: id-selectors start with `#`. You used a class selector instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is more complicated than is needed, you don't need to have `h1` elements nested in the `div`'s.  It appears that you are using `h1` to get large, bold text, but you can simply add the font styles directly to the `div`'s.

You can also simplify the CSS by taking advantage of the CSS cascade and grouping selectors, for example, `.Line1, .Line2, .Line3` for those CSS rules
common to all the lines.

You originally specified the line-height to be 10px, which will cause problems
if the text had to wrap to 2 or more lines.  In this case, you can use the
default line height and you gain nothing by setting it to 10px.

You can use margins to open up spacing between the text lines, but to prevent
the margins from the child elements from collapsing with the parent element `.outer`, apply `overflow: auto` to create a block formatting context.

You can read up on block formatting contexts in the CSS2 specification.

Finally, to position your video link, simply use a class selector (`.video`) 
instead of an id (`#video`).  You had the right idea but an error in the syntax.

```css
.outer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto; /* Start a block formatting context so that margins don't collapse */
}
.Line1, .Line2, .Line3 {
    font-size:26px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
.Line1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.Line2 {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.Line3 {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.video {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="Line1">The Simple Way to Trading Profit</div>
    <div class="Line2">trading forex stocks commodities futures</div>
    <div class="Line3">The TradeMap. Trade like a pro.</div>
    <div class="video">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DYkSNur2Rc" rel="lightvideo"><img alt="How to Trade Video" src="/images/WatchVideo.png" style="width: 136px; height: 34px;" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How strange. The "Comments" help text tells me to "avoid thanks." Maybe I'm just old and old fashioned, but when someone helps me as much as you have Marc, I feel grateful and inspired to say thank you for your time and efforts. I'm new to CSS and you have most certainly been an excellent guide.

Comment: Your comment is much appreciated, glad to help! Remember to up vote the answer to show that the questions is answered and taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is `.video` which would target `class="video"`, but your `div` has `id="video"`.  Either change your div to `<div class="video">` or change your CSS selector to `#video`.

Comment: Your answer is valid, so the down vote seems out of place.